# Angular 9: Indian Number Format with number pipe and locale 'en-IN'?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have code like this in angular 9:

main.ts

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,{
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-IN' }]
})
```

test.component.html

```
{{total | number:'1.2-2':'en-IN'}}
```

test.component.ts

```
total = 155000;
```

I am using number pipe with Locale 'en-IN'.

I want result like this: `1,55,000`

But I am getting like this: `155,000`

I want result in Indian number format with Locale and number pipe only.

How to achieve this with number pipe and locale 'en-IN'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To override default locale we need to import import-global-variants-of-the-locale-data, Try the following.

**app.module.ts**

```
import "@angular/common/locales/global/en-IN";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-IN" }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y1ylmr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I have used this code: import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core'; 
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,{
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-IN' }]
})   Why this is not working???

Comment: If you want to override locale then you have to follow this steps https://angular.io/guide/i18n#steps-to-localize-your-app

Comment: What is the difference between this two approaches??

Comment: The difference is  registerLocaldata used to add aditional locale, whereas provind value is override defautl locale.

Comment: In order to override Locale we need to import  global variants of the locale data as mentioned in the doc:https://angular.io/guide/i18n#import-global-variants-of-the-locale-data

Comment: For some reason setting locale on main.ts not working in stackblitz,

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `localeIn` and register that in `registerLocaleData`

```
import localeIn from '@angular/common/locales/en-IN';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
registerLocaleData(localeIn);
```

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8jd54r

Comment: why my approach with import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core'; is not working ??